# XMLHttpRequest with Hebrew Characters

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xmlhttprequest, hebrew

I'm having this code which seem to screw up itself when the text in the `XMLHttpRequest` contains Hebrew characters, so I've made a small example to demonstrate the problem.

The small code example loads the page and then replaces the content of a div with the content it got from the server.
Since it calls the same webpage then it should replace it with the same content.

The code works fine when the button inside the div contains letters in English, but if the letters are beyond ASCII 127 then it screws the button.

I've made some tests and saw that if I save the file as Unicode, then it works ok...
The problem is that I can't save this file as Unicode since it:

1. doubles the size of the file
2. the hardware that writes some of the data in that html file, write it in ASCII

The small example just load itself:

```
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Test</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY onload="readPage()">
<Div id='Hello'>
<Button>שלום</Button>
</Div>
<Script>
var xmlHttp;
function readPage()
{
    xmlHttp=GetXmlHttpObject();

    if (xmlHttp==null)
    {
        alert ("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
        return;
    }

    var url="/xampp/2.html?dummy=" + new Date().getTime();
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged;
    xmlHttp.open("GET",url, true);
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1");
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Accept-Charset", "ISO-8859-1");
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}

function stateChanged()
{
    if (xmlHttp.readyState==4)
    {
        var x = ""; 
        //alert(xmlHttp.responseXML);
        //alert(xmlHttp.responseText);
        if (xmlHttp.responseText.match(/<Div id='Hello'>([\s\S]*?)<\/Div>/i))
        {
            x = xmlHttp.responseText.match(/<Div id='Hello'>([\s\S]*?)<\/Div>/i)[1];
            //x = x.replace(/"/g,'');


            var pdata= document.all ? document.all["Hello"] :
                document.getElementById("Hello");

            alert(pdata.innerHTML);
            alert(x);
            pdata.innerHTML=x;
            alert(pdata.innerHTML);
        }

    }
}
function GetXmlHttpObject()
{
    var xmlHttp=null;
    try
    {
        // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
        xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    catch (e)
    {
        // Internet Explorer
        try
        {
            xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch (e)
        {
            xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
    }
    return xmlHttp;
}
</Script>
</BODY></HTML>
```

I tried changing the char set and the content type, but it doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

(btw, I cannot use any `jQuery` stuff).

Thanks.

Comment: Why you don't whant to use UTF-8?

Comment: You can't have it both ways - Hebrew characters will always be outside of ASCII. You need to use some encoding where these characters are legal (`iso-8859-8` for example). If your file is ASCII, it cannot contain Hebrew characters.

Comment: please explain what it means "screws the button"? what error are you getting?

Comment: @pomaxa - OP explained in the question. Both for file size and because the process generating some of the content in the files will only produce ASCII.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I'm not sure what the web server of XAMPP sends for the specific HTML I use, but on the specific hardware, we wrote the web server and it sends:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
MIME-version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html
Content-length: 11280
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
Connection: Keep-Alive
Age: 0
```

One solution would be saving the web page as Unicode, which will not be good for us.
The other option, which seem to work, is to tell the browser that we want a specific encoding.
In this case Windows-1255.

All I had to do, is to change the header that is sent from the website so it will also contain the charset, and now it works fine:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
MIME-version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=Windows-1255
Content-length: 11280
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
Connection: Keep-Alive
Age: 0
```

Answer (score 3):

you can try to encode manually the letters. it is a very slow and bad solution but it might help you
q contains for Hebrew data
(on javascript)

```
q=q.replace(/א/gi,"%E0");
q=q.replace(/ב/gi,"%E1");
q=q.replace(/ג/gi,"%E2");
q=q.replace(/ד/gi,"%E3");
q=q.replace(/ה/gi,"%E4");
q=q.replace(/ו/gi,"%E5");
q=q.replace(/ז/gi,"%E6");
q=q.replace(/ח/gi,"%E7");
q=q.replace(/ט/gi,"%E8");
q=q.replace(/י/gi,"%E9");
q=q.replace(/כ/gi,"%EB");
q=q.replace(/ך/gi,"%EA");
q=q.replace(/ל/gi,"%EC");
q=q.replace(/מ/gi,"%EE");
q=q.replace(/ם/gi,"%ED");
q=q.replace(/נ/gi,"%F0");
q=q.replace(/ן/gi,"%EF");
q=q.replace(/ס/gi,"%F1");
q=q.replace(/ע/gi,"%F2");
q=q.replace(/פ/gi,"%F4");
q=q.replace(/ף/gi,"%F3");
q=q.replace(/צ/gi,"%F6");
q=q.replace(/ץ/gi,"%F5");
q=q.replace(/ק/gi,"%F7");
q=q.replace(/ר/gi,"%F8");
q=q.replace(/ש/gi,"%F9");
q=q.replace(/ת/gi,"%FA");
```

Comment: Well, it is not just with hebrew, but with any character within the non-printable ascii code. The problem is that responseText is already "corrupted". This is why I'm alerting it in a messagebox... I see that it is already wrong. It's like the XMLHttpRequest doesn't work with those characters.